# Unrelated select firing when updates another slice of state

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a "feature" state in my NxRx (v7) enabled application, that looks like the following:

**State**

```
    export interface DataPageState {  
        dataReceivedTimestamp: number; 

        formData: PageSaveDataState;      // <--- setting this

        previewDataHeaderNames: string[]  // } <--- calls selector for these
        previewData: string[][];          // }

        error: string;
        isLoading: boolean;  
    }
```

**Selectors**

I have a selector to get both `previewDataHeaderNames`  and `previewData` - returned as an object as I use them to populate a data grid:

```
export const getDataPreviewFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<DataPreviewPageState>(NgRxStateNames.dataPreviewPage);

    /** Get preview data */
    export const getPreviewData = createSelector(
        getDataPreviewFeatureState,
        (state: DataPreviewPageState) => {
            return { previewData: state.previewData, headers: state.previewDataHeaderNames };
        }
    );
```

**Reducer**

In my reducer, I have the following to update the `formData` slice of state. I Have a form on the same page and I use this to save its state (as well as data grid layout etc):

```
case myActions.ActionTypes.SetPreviewFormData: {
    this.logger.info('SetPreviewFormData');
    const newState = { ...action.payload, timeStamp: this.timeService.getUtcNowTimestamp() }
    return { ...state, formData: newState };
  }
```

**Selector firing when I set the formData**

Finally, in my component code, I have a selector for the `getPreviewData`

```
  this.subs.sink = this.store$.select(fromDataPreview.getPreviewData).subscribe(previewData => {      
    this.loadGridData(previewData.headers, previewData.previewData);
  });
```

When I route to another page, just before I route I call an action to set the form data as per the `case myActions.ActionTypes.SetPreviewFormData` above.

But when I call this, I have the above selector fire, and so my method to set the (already set) grid data is called again. If I comment out my dispatch to `myActions.ActionTypes.SetPreviewFormData` this is behaviour no longer happens.

Why does setting one slice of the state fire a select different slice? From what I understand the whole idea of the selectors was to only get the notification when the property involved in that selector, otherwise may as well just have one selector that returns the whole state.

Why is this happening, or am I wrong in my assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have to double check, but my assumption would be:
Your reducer returns a complete new object for the state thru the spreading syntax (which is correct):

```
 return { previewData: state.previewData, headers: state.previewDataHeaderNames };
```

Now, the selectors cache resets and all selectors are recomputed.
See e.g. https://medium.com/swlh/memoization-with-selectors-in-ngrx-c60e67a08161, explains it rather well imo.

I think you might achieve what you want with the following pattern:

First, define two selectors for the two single state attributes you require:

```
export const getPreviewData = createSelector(
    getDataPreviewFeatureState,
    (state: DataPreviewPageState) => state.previewData 
    }
);

export const getPreviewDataHeaderNames = createSelector(
    getDataPreviewFeatureState,
    (state: DataPreviewPageState) => state.previewDataHeaderNames 
    }
);
```

Then combine these two selectors in order to define the selector for your component:

```
    export const getPreviewDataWithNames = createSelector(
        getPreviewData,
        getPreviewDataHeaderNames,
        (previewData, previewDataHeaderNames) => ({ previewData, previewDataHeaderNames })
        
    );
```

Now the following should occur: Since the references for previewData and previewDataHeaderNames do not change and the selector has no direct reference to your state, your combined selector does not recompute.

Comment: thankyou for that explanation. The above works. I think I see, the selectors look at the inputs (not outputs), so we first need another selector to return any  inputs we don't expect to always change when the state does.I now think I have been doing a lot (most) of my selectors wrong, as I often have "state" as a direct input. So really often we may need two selectors for every property - one to get the property from the state, and then another than then uses this output as an input which we then use in the component.

Comment: Well using state is input is mostly fine if you use a single attribute of state as return value. NGRX checks for object reference via the distinctUntilChanged Operator. if say the previewData reference does not change, it would not emit another value. Sothe getPreviewData  Selector in my example is completely fine. But in your combined selector, distinctUntilChanged does not work, because you have to build a new reference of the returned object via { previewData, previewDataHeaderNames }.

Comment: Yes, I see. As the doco says `distinctUntilChanged uses === comparison by default, object references must match!` That's good, it means we still get it for free for simple values.